# План выполнения запроса: Выбор соединения

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Подскажите, по какому критерию оптимизатор запросов осуществляет выбор соединения таблиц?

Я попытался соединить таблицу на саму себя по кластеризованному индексу и ожидал получить `merge join`, но по факту получил вложенные циклы.

Если верить WIKI, то необходимым условием является отсортированность полей по которым выполняется соединение.

Comment: Боюсь у вас слишком сложный вопрос. Оптимизаторы запросов руководствуются внутренними алгоритмами и разные версии конкретной СУБД могут идти разными путями. Кроме того в крупных СУБД оптимизаторы собирают статистику по данным и индексам и могут менять план выполнения в зависимости от предсказываемого кол-ва записей результата (селективности запроса). Если нужно конкретное поведение следует пользоваться подсказками оптимизатору. И то не всегда помогает

Comment: А еще вспомнил забавную ситуацию с сайбейсом (наследником которого является MS Sql). Он динамически менял план выполнения в зависимости от кол-ва различных одновременных запросов в БД и блокировок на страницах индекса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вкратце, то критерие один - выбираются те типы соединения которые приводят к минимальному cost-у запроса.